# A linear map with an orthonormal eigenbasis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Here is a proposition my professor stated in class:

> Let V be a finite dimensional inner product space, with $ T: V \to V$ a linear map. Let $\gamma$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of V.
>
> 1. The standard matrix $[T]_\gamma^\gamma$ is diagonal
> 2. The standard matrix of the adjoint $T^*$, $([T]_\gamma^\gamma)^*$ is also diagonal. Moreover, $T \circ T^* = T^* \circ T$

However, wouldn't we have this for a non-orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of V?

> Definition: let V be a finite dim. inner product space. A linear map $T: V \to V$ is said to be normal iff $T \circ T^* = T^* \circ T$

He then proceeds with an example for a linear map $T: \mathbb{C}^2  \to \mathbb{C}^2$. He finds that there are two distinct roots and states that because $T$ has an eigenbasis, then $T$ must have an orthonormal eigenbasis, since you could simply use G-S to get an orthonormal eigenbasis.

I think this is incorrect, specifically because you are not guaranteed to have eigenvectors after performing G-S on them.

My question here is: is it not the case that $T \circ T^* = T^* \circ T$ so long as you take $T$ with respect to the basis of eigenvectors, which produces a diagonal matrix?

> a linear map is said to be self-adjoint $T: V \to V$ if $T = T^*$

> for a real inner product space, T has an orthonormal eigenbasis iff T is self-adjoint

I have the same question here, where from my understanding, if you have an eigenbasis, then you have a diagonal matrix, and in the real case, you can always say that $T = T^*$ if you take the transformation with respect to that basis, but how does this guarantee an orthonormal eigenbasis?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're assuming you can simultaneously diagonalize $T$ and $T^*$ - if you can, then yes, they will commute. But if not? (i.e. if $T^*$ is not diagonal under this change of basis).

For example, take $T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ in the standard basis. Then $T^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, and so $TT^* = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ while $T^*T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and if $TT^*\neq T^*T$ under the standard basis, then they're not going to be equal under some other basis.

The issue here is that $T$ and $T^*$ don't have the same eigenvectors, the eigenvalues for both matrices are $1$ and $-1$, and $T$ has corresponding eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$, but the eigenvectors for $T^*$ are $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The statement I was making is that if you can diagonalize T, then you can take $T^*$ with respect to the basis of diagonalization, and it will always equal T

Comment: what do you mean "you can take $^∗$ with respect to the basis of diagonalization"?

Comment: alternatively, take the $T$ I have written above, do whatever it is you propose to do, and tell me if you get the result predicted by your statement

Comment: I was stating that if you have $T^*$ and you have a basis of eigenvectors, would this not be always equal to $T$, in the real case (taking the conjugate transpose)? Why is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors a requirement?

Comment: No, this is not generally true, a matrix $T$ is normal (commutes with its conj. transpose) if and only if there is a set of orthonormal eigenvectors. Being diagonalizable is a much weaker condition.

Comment: Isn’t the conjugate transpose of a diagonal matrix itself? And a diagonal matrix exists even if the eigenbasis is not orthonormal? So how are they not the same condition? That is my real question here

Comment: Suppose $T$ is diagonalizable, i.e. there is some basis so that the matrix for $T$ is diagonal with respect to that basis, i.e. $P^{-1}TP = D$ where the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $T$ and form such a basis.

I think what you are assuming is that $T^*$ will somehow also be diagonal in this basis, but that isn't true generally. That is, $P^{-1}T^*P$ will not necessarily be diagonal.

Comment: In fact, if you suppose that they are simultaneously diagonalizable, $P^{-1}TP = D_1, P^{-1}T^*P = D_2$, then $P^{-1}TT^*P = D_1D_2 = D_2D_1 = P^{-1}T^*TP$ since diagonal matrices obviously commute. But then this leads immediately to $TT^* = T^*T$, i.e. if $T$ and $T^*$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, then $T$ is normal.